# Is the data buffer from socket.on('data') safe to retain?

Tags: node.js, sockets

If I do this:

```javascript
const net = require('net');
const allData = [];
const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
    socket.on('data', (data) => {
        allData.push(data); // store data; not a copy of it
    });
});
server.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');

setInterval(() => {
    console.log(allData);
}, 5000);
```

Can I guarantee that the data stored in `allData` will be consistent? Or is it possible for `net` to re-use buffers for later data?

Testing with the code above and sending simple cURL requests implies that it will *not* be overwritten, but I can't find anything in the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_data) to support this, and the [code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/net.js) is something of a labyrinth.

Can I rely on this behaviour, or must I make a copy of the buffer to be safe?

Comment: That's safe (as in no, the buffers won't be reused) but you'll eventually run out of memory, so that's another issue entirely.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts are you sure it's safe? how do you know? as for the example, obviously this is super-simplified; my actual use-case is a short-lived queue of data which only hangs around until it can be processed.

Comment: What you have is a standard pattern for aggregating event-based data, which is used in several places in their documentation. Node.js doesn't re-use buffers unless they have been garbage collected, and objects are not subject to GC if your program still has references to them.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Cool, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by Patrick Roberts in the comments, the best indication that this is safe to do comes from a Node.js example performing similar actions. After some hunting I found this example (for `http` rather than `net` but they are closely linked);

> ```
> let body = [];
> request.on('data', (chunk) => {
>   body.push(chunk);
> }).on('end', () => {
>   body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
>   // at this point, `body` has the entire request body stored in it as a string
> });
> ```

Source: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/#request-body

This implies that http data is consistent at least for the duration of the connection, and it's not too much of a stretch to assume this means it's consistent indefinitely.

Comment: I would not rely on that for socket, since it rely on buffer chunk, not on string that are not mutable. this is even expressly indicated in the documentation linked : "if you know it's going to be string data, the best thing to do is collect the data in an array"